# How scheduler knows about all the nodes for filtering in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

While studying about scheduling in k8s,
Ive searched for hours to know how scheduler knows about all the nodes for filtering
but i failed to get informations about it.
I guess that the scheduler gets node informations from etcd through api-server
Is it right?
Big thanks to the future repliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at this article on *[Creating custom scheduler on kubrnetes](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-custom-scheduler/)* which explains in details and open-sourced the project in Golang on [this repository](https://github.com/martonsereg/random-scheduler/blob/master/cmd/scheduler/main.go).

But briefly, *the Api-Server* periodically updates the list of available nodes in the cluster using some techniques. *The scheduler* uses *Informers* API to get the list of available pods from the API-Server. This list is also cached using the Informers to decrease the number of API calls. also the Informer watches the API-Server for new changes on the nodes list.
Then the scheduler binds pods to the proper node using whatever algorithm integrated.

Comment: thank you for the answer .  Ill check the post you suggested